# "Module not found" error in react app, despite having already installed the module

Tags: reactjs, node.js, node-modules, yarnpkg

I'm adding VR functionality to an existing React app, and so I installed a library called '@coconut-xr/natuerlich'. I have tried this library before in a fresh project and used it just fine, following along with their examples without problem. However, when I tried adding it to the existing React app it does not run.

I import from the library in the exact same way as their examples and as I did in my fresh project.

```
import {
  XRCanvas,
  Hands,
  Controllers
} from '@coconut-xr/natuerlich/defaults';
import {
  useXR,
  NonImmersiveCamera,
  ImmersiveSessionOrigin
} from '@coconut-xr/natuerlich/react';
```

But when I run the app, I get a `Module not found: Can't resolve '@coconut-xr/natuerlich/defaults'` error.
The package is in the `package.json` dependencies, I've tried deleting `node_modules` and running `yarn cache clear` then `yarn install`, I've tried removing the package from the dependencies and adding it again with `yarn add @coconut-xr/natuerlich`, but nothing works.

If it's relevant, the fresh project was a next.js app using npm to manage dependencies, while the app I'm trying to add the library to was created with create-react-app and uses yarn.

Can anyone help me out?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Turns out it was a version conflict with other dependencies in my project. Should anyone find this also having this same problem with coconut-xr, it was due to react-scripts being version 4 instead of 5.